# Customizing Save Attribute Button in Woocommerce Wordpress admin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on Woocommerce plugin because there is a problem there.
I tried to create a variable option product by Woocommerce and every time I choose an attribute and click "Save Attribute" button, it keeps spinning and never ending. 
I want to dig into the source code of this button to customize something but don't know which is its location. Can you guys let me know which is it? and if anybody has hit this problem, can you please give me some suggestions on fixing this?

Thank you very much and hope to hear from you guys as soon as possible.

Comment: It's impossible for us to debug your site for you and so this question is off-topic. However, the steps provided below are a good path to help you debug it yourself. Sound like you should report the problem to Ultimate VC addons. I always preferred Beaver Builder, I had too many problems with Visual Composer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like theme/plugins conflict.
Try to:

1. Switch your theme to the defalut WP theme.
2. Disable all plugins except WooCommerce (do you use last version of WooCommerce plugin? If not - update).
3. Test attributes saving again.

Update:
Do you have any JS errors when you try to save attributes? How to check JS errors in the browser console: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/77337

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried your method, it worked with default theme and just WooCommerce plugin actived. But when I switched back to new theme that I have been using, the problem is back. What should I do next? Thanks and look forward to hearing from you.

Comment: Hi, when I click on "Save Attribute" I saw these errors as below picture link: http://imgur.com/a/LLF74

Comment: Disable `ultimate-woocomposer-backend`. I think it's a part of Ultimate VC Addons plugin?

Comment: yes, I disabled that plugin and "Save Attribute" button works. But now when I click on "Add" it keeps spinning again. And of course, without this plugin something can't display on my website. The error when  I clicked on it as below url: http://imgur.com/a/hb9Ef